# How to parse date string to Date?

Tags: java, date, format

How do I parse the date string below into a `Date` object?

```
String target = "Thu Sep 28 20:29:30 JST 2000";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("E MM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy");
Date result =  df.parse(target);
```

Throws exception...

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Sep 28 20:29:30 JST 2000"
        at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: For anyone visiting this question in 2019 or later I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). I am immodest enough to recommend [my own answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56374732/5772882).

Answer (score 177, accepted):

The pattern is wrong. You have a 3-letter day abbreviation, so it must be `EEE`. You have a 3-letter month abbreviation, so it must be `MMM`. As those day and month abbreviations are locale sensitive, you'd like to explicitly specify the `SimpleDateFormat` locale to English as well, otherwise it will use the platform default locale which may not be English per se.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String target = "Thu Sep 28 20:29:30 JST 2000";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date result =  df.parse(target);  
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

This prints here

```
Thu Sep 28 07:29:30 BOT 2000
```

which is correct as per my timezone.

I would also reconsider if you wouldn't rather like to use `HH` instead of `kk`. Read the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for details about valid patterns.

Comment: Nope, still throwing same error, I've tried with zzz too and no luck. I'm going to check the doc now, thanks for the link.

Comment: Runs fine here (after removing `String` from your 2nd code line). Your problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: hmm right, I'll remove the "string", but still not working on my local, looking at other places now.. interesting..

Comment: By the way, where does this date string come from? It look very much like the default outcome of `java.util.Date#toString()`. Aren't you doing some things wrongly? (passing dates around as strings instead of dates)

Comment: I had "throws ParseException next to the method declaration line and after I removed it and change to try/catch block, it worked. But your example has "throws Exception" too.. mystery.

Comment: The date string value came from database which was stored in HTML input field and I picked it up and wanting to convert to Date type for column update. I kind of feeling wrong but would appriciate if there is better way.

Comment: @BalusC: remove the "throws Exception" from method line and change to try/catch. My local test shows that try/catch works but your version still throws an error. (though I'm not sure why.. gotta check exception again)

Comment: Works fine here. It's legitimately valid. You have to be more clear about that "an error". As to passing the value around, I'd rather use a fixed and same pattern for formatting (displaying/editing in HTML) and parsing (processing request parameter). E.g. `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

Comment: You are right, I should not use pure toString output for form input, cuz i'm having super tough time handling it. Maybe convert to MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss would be much friendlier.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a working example:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class j4496359 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String target = "Thu Sep 28 20:29:30 JST 2000";
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
            Date result =  df.parse(target);
            System.out.println(result); 
        } catch (ParseException pe) {
            pe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Will print:

```
Thu Sep 28 13:29:30 CEST 2000
```

Comment: I've tried that already.. it didn't work :(

Comment: Updated my post with tested code ;)

Answer (score 13):

```
String target = "27-09-1991 20:29:30";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date result =  df.parse(target);
System.out.println(result);
```

This works fine?

Comment: I think you meant: "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"

Answer (score 7):

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy");
```

and

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss Z yyyy");
```

still runs. However, if your code throws an exception it is because your tool or jdk or any other reason. Because **I got same error** in my IDE but please check these http://ideone.com/Y2cRr (online ide) with [ZZZ](http://ideone.com/Y2cRr) and with [Z](http://ideone.com/4TIwm)

output is : `Thu Sep 28 11:29:30 GMT 2000`

Comment: You are right, my IDE which is NetBean3.9 and run the exactly same code throws an error while online IDE does not.

Comment: I had also same problem. I know this feeling :) correct code but wrong output. update your jdk there will not any problem

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue, and I set the `Locale` to `US`, then it work.

```
static DateFormat visitTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy",Locale.US);
```

for `String` `"Sun Jul 08 00:06:30 UTC 2012"`

Comment: I had to set the Locale.US also for new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.US) to parse"Wed Jan 25 11:13:11 +0100 2012"

Answer (score 0):

A parse exception is a checked exception, so you must catch it with a try-catch when working with parsing Strings to Dates, as @miku suggested...