# How to convert Thu Dec 17 15:37:43 GMT+05:30 2015 string to Date in android

Tags: android

```
SimpleDateFormat format =new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+05:30"));
try {
    long diff2=format.parse(accidentReports.getAccidentDate());
}
```

getting this output :: Thu Dec 17 15:37:43 GMT+05:30 5

Comment: Your code doesn't print anything - where are you getting that output?

Comment: In which format u want the Date?

Comment: What is setting `accidentReports.getAccidentDate()`? Your format string looks right to me, are you sure that the input is not setting the date to the year 5?

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to parse output of new Date().toString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713825/how-to-parse-output-of-new-date-tostring)

Comment: It may also be a kind of duplicate of [Returning NumberFormatException form SimpleDateFormat in Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63500822/returning-numberformatexception-form-simpledateformat-in-java-code).

Answer (score 10):

If you required Date Object form String use:

```
    Date date=null;
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
    String temp = "Thu Dec 17 15:37:43 GMT+05:30 2015";
    try {
        date = formatter.parse(temp);
        Log.e("formated date ", date + "");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Your OutPut is
 
`Thu Dec 17 15:37:43 GMT+05:30 2015`: 
in Date Object

For Again Convert it to String:

```
    String formateDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(date);
    Log.v("output date ",formateDate);
```

Now your output is:

```
12-17-2015
```

Answer (score 6):

In Kotlin,

```
   private fun convertToCustomFormat(dateStr: String?): String {
        val utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
        val sourceFormat = SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy")
        val destFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-YYYY HH:mm aa")
        sourceFormat.timeZone = utc
        val convertedDate = sourceFormat.parse(dateStr)
        return destFormat.format(convertedDate)
    }
```

Input Date :

```
Sat Dec 19 12:50:57 GMT+05:30 2020
```

Output Date Format :

```
19-Dec-2020 12:50 PM
```

Explanation :

### Format Explanation

- EEE : Day ( Mon )
- MMM : Month in words ( Dec )
- MM  : Day in Count ( 324 )
- mm  : Month ( 12 )
- dd  : Date ( 3 )
- HH  : Hours ( 12 )
- mm  : Minutes ( 50 )
- ss  : Seconds ( 34 )
- yyyy: Year ( 2020 ) //both yyyy and YYYY are same
- YYYY: Year ( 2020 )
- zzz : GMT+05:30
- aa  : ( AM / PM )

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android look into [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) -

Comment: - or see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: Also your `destFormat` format pattern is incorrect and will give you surprises around new year. You need to beware of the case of format pattern letters. *//both yyyy and YYYY are same* This is not true.

Answer (score 2):

### *java.time*

The `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> .

**Using modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "Thu Dec 17 15:37:43 GMT+05:30 2015";
        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM d H:m:s O u", Locale.ENGLISH);
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtfInput);

        // Default string i.e. OffsetDateTime#toString
        System.out.println(odt);

        // A custom string
        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssO", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String formatted = odt.format(dtfOutput);
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2015-12-17T15:37:43+05:30
2015-12-17T15:37:43GMT+5:30
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Please check my solution i have used before:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
    try {
        String temp = "Thu Dec 17 15:37:43 GMT+05:30 2015";
        Date expiry = formatter.parse(temp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry this may be late to answer, but it may help to anyone in near future.
just call this simple method while passing your date (Thu Dec 17 15:37:43 GMT+05:30 2015) and you will get result like this : 2015-12-17

```
 private String getFormattedDate(Date timeZone){

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String formattedDate = df.format(timeZone);
    return formattedDate;

}
```

Just keep in mind, this is a Date formatted value not a String value.

how to call :

```
 getFormattedDate(date);
```