# Returning NumberFormatException form SimpleDateFormat in Java code

Tags: java, simpledateformat, numberformatexception

I have declared a SimpleDateFormat object as a static field inside the constant file as follows,

Constants.java

```
public static final SimpleDateFormat GENERAL_TZ_FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
```

and inside my class file my implementation like this.

```
String fDate = getTextValue(empNo, "firstDate");
if (null != fDate && !fDate.isEmpty()) {
    try {
        Date date = (Date)(Constants.GENERAL_TZ_FORMATTER).parse(fDate);
        issue.setDate(date.getTime());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        logUtil.error(LOG, e+ "date : " + date);
    }
}
```

Error :

```
Exception while importing data. package name.SecureException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
```

My problem is, in some cases, this throws a `NumberFormatException` (a very rare situation), so I've been wondering about that an I did a diagnosis, and most of them are explaining this case might happen due to that SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe. If this is the case, I'm not clear how this code running in a multiple thread environment without using multiple threads, would it make the input to DateFormat.parse() an empty string?

[Java's SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe article](https://www.callicoder.com/java-simpledateformat-thread-safety-issues/#:%7E:text=Algorithms-,Java%27s%20SimpleDateFormat%20is%20not%20thread%2Dsafe%2C%20Use,carefully%20in%20multi%2Dthreaded%20environments&text=SimpleDateFormat%20is%20used%20to%20format%20and%20parse%20dates%20in%20Java.&text=One%20of%20the%20most%20important,environments%20if%20not%20used%20properly.)

I have tried to solve this problem, but It's really hard to recreate this issue, I like to know your ideas about this and it will help me to find a better solution. Really appreciate your suggestions.
Thank you.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't use `SimpleDateFormat` anyway. You probably stumbled upon such case where `SimpleDateFormat` is troublesome. [This is not the only reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api), however. You need to move to the newer Java 8 Date and Time API, available in the  `java.time` package. They're absolutely thread-safe because of their immutable nature. In your case, use `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: @MCEmperor Really appreciate your suggestion, could you able to explain to me why this `SimpleDateFormat` not suitable for my code? If you can add a few words, it will be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as the comment below your post already mentioned, you shouldn't use `SimpleDateFormat` anyway.

You have probably stumbled upon such case where `SimpleDateFormat` is troublesome. This is not the only reason, however. [This Stackoverflow post explains why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api) it is so troublesome. One of the reasons in that very same post mention `SimpleDateFormat` not being *thread-safe*. Thread-safety is that when multiple processes act upon the formatter, that is, leverage the formatter to format a date, and that no incorrect, inaccurate or undefined results occur because of interference.

[Your link to the article on Callicoder](https://www.callicoder.com/java-simpledateformat-thread-safety-issues) explains pretty well *why* `SimpleDateFormat` cause trouble. The post mentions the same exception as you got:

> ```
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
> ```

In short, the threads interfere when they use the formatter, because the formatter is not synchronized. That means that the `SimpleDateFormat` class does not enforce that one thread must wait until some other thread has finished with modifying its internal state. Three of the used classes are [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.java), [`DateFormat`](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/text/DateFormat.java) and [`FieldPosition`](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/text/FieldPosition.java).

[image: TryItOnline!] [Here's erroneous code in action](https://tio.run/##jVNNb9swDL37VxC@1EUQw8lhGJIV2GEtegla1LkNOygymyixpUCi3ASDf3tGf7R1nGwYYdgy9cT3HiVtRSnGZo96m@1OJ1XsjSXYcjImPFD8LKzD@4PEPSmj58EFIOVMjj8E4YOxhaBziCeVx/XklbQ0WnprUVN8f0DpydgUbankf4LdPAhkLpyDhVAafgcBcOytKpkPHAlSEobywA0Td6Dx7QIXhUeO8WIxzrKb5c3j46woZs6Ft/OOxq9yLt@xlEZlULCKKCWr9PrnLxB27W5ZFHTRTkDGDDxk1nCaTL6Oky/j6XQ5SWZJ/YRd9ToGPQEc/N99IFzMDh7UAbPlxqLIno3Jo0nCUt9rvXitxSpHIOF2neP3XNRXWcf3pxKtVRmeZTvDjVPr9cWqBlMflrqHUWezJ6GO6uOv6hl9NTZSmkCxsGTOn28wSerBaDQkGfQgdn5VKIpqVz2q6rP2xYKNp8y8sfwWXl09NI3JTzPnW9fXRPY4UFgvaJBsZnjU4qbkX3qTHh1hERvPMKajXEdh6qVE5159nh@huYlZSxDCqCHpmwYpSG4gOr@xgMMeXiNq11hrbFMa4zXSgpnFmo/HNZJ/1Me2bEpC7pZWSIzOtqZ9V8Hp9Ac).

#### Use `java.time`

You need to move to the newer Java 8 Date and Time API, available in the `java.time` package. They're absolutely thread-safe because of their immutable nature. In your case, use `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`:

```
public static final DateTimeFormatter GENERAL_TZ_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
```

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(fDate, GENERAL_TZ_FORMATTER);
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();

// Your setDate should really accept an Instant:
issue.setDate(instant);
// If that's REALLY not possible, then you can convert it to an integer
// value equal to the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970, midnight
//issue.setDate(instant.toEpochMilli());
```