# Easy way to generate SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat, datetime-parsing

I am having this string "Mon Nov 11 10:36:53 GMT+02:00 2019". What is the pattern when using SimpleDateFormat();? Is there some way I can test or generate it without multiple try and error?

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to parse output of new Date().toString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713825/how-to-parse-output-of-new-date-tostring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

> What is the pattern when using SimpleDateFormat();?

My suggestion is that you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. On Android — and on your API level too — you can use java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ROOT);

    String stringWereHaving = "Mon Nov 11 10:36:53 GMT+02:00 2019";
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(stringWereHaving, formatter);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output is:

> 2019-11-11T10:36:53+02:00[Etc/GMT-2]

The only confusing thing here is that the sign used in the time zone name `Etc/GMT-2` has been intentionally reversed compared to normal usage.

Only if you need an old-fashioned `Date` object for a legacy API not yet upgraded to java.time, convert like this:

```
    Instant i = dateTime.toInstant();
    Date oldfashionedDate = DateTimeUtils.toDate(i);
    System.out.println(oldfashionedDate);
```

> Mon Nov 11 09:36:53 CET 2019

Output comes from my computer in Europe/Copenhagen time zone, so the hour of day is adjusted by 1 hour compared to your input at offset `02:00. We have got the same point in time as in the string.

> Is there some way I can test or generate it without multiple try and
>   error?

There’s always Java SimpleDateFormat Online Tester. I give you the link at the bottom. I don’t know of a similar service for `DateTimeFormatter`. Many of the patterns are the same, also the one I am using above, so it’s probably worthwhile trying.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Java SimpleDateFormat Online Tester](http://www.sdfonlinetester.info/#)

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Try This

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss 'GMT' Z yyyy");

        System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(new Date()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean " Is there some way I can test or generate it without multiple try and error?"

BTW, I'm using `DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(<put your desired pattern here via STRING>);`

and get the current date:

```
 Date date = new Date();
 String result = dateFormat.format(date); // formatting the date and passing it on string.
```

sample code:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM. dd, yyyy EEE HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();

result = dateFormat.format(date);
```

Output : Nov. 13, 2019 Wed 17:02:00