# How to convert Standard Date into minutes in java?

Tags: java, date

How to convert standard output of date into number of minutes?

I have output from my command as:

> Mon Mar  4 12:33:58 2013

and I need to convert it into number of minutes say `minutes1`.

because I have a code which gives number of minutes for current time and the code is:

```
public class DateToMinutes {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Date date = new Date();

      long now = ((date.getTime()) / (60000));

      System.out.println("Total Minutes are  " + now);

   }

}
```

the output of this will be in minutes say `minutes2`.

I need to compare both `minutes1` and `minutes2`.

since I am unable to convert Standard date into `minutes1`, it's not possible right now.

Comment: look at parse method of SimpleDateFormat http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: (1) Time zone is crucial for the operation. Be specific about the time zone of your command output or else incorrect results are most likely. (2) The `Date` class was the right one to use in 2013. Today you should use [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) instead. (3) What is the point in obtaining the minutes? It seems simpler just to compare the `Date` objects with `before()` or `after()` (or better, their `java.time` counterparts with `isBefore()` or `isAfter()`).

Answer (score 3):

look at parse method of SimpleDateFormat, there you'll find formats used for converting dates.

[Javadocs here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

In your case something like this should work:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy");
Date theDate = sdf.parse ("Mon Mar 4 12:33:58 2013");
long minutes2 = theDate.getTime() / 60000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simpledate formatter.

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("mm");
Date one = ...
Date two = ...
formatter.format( one) ); // only the minutes remain
formatter.format( two) ); // only the minutes remain

// do whatever you want.
```

Answer (score 0):

Determining minutes1 is **parsing a date** and transforming it.

Related issues can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496359/how-to-parse-date-string-to-date) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-date-in-java).

This should do the job based on your description of the date format:

```
SimpleDateFormat yourStandardDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss yyyy");
Date date = yourStandardDateFormat.parse( stringRepresentingDate );
long minutes1 = date.getTime() / 60000l;
```

For reference, see [SimpleDateFormat documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)