# How to parse String to Date

Tags: java

I meet the problem with this code:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date date = df.parse("2013-03-07 23:59:00.0")
```

I get the exception:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-03-07 23:59:00.0"

How can I convert this kind of String to Date?

Comment: ...your date is not in the format `MM/dd/yyyy`, so why did you write that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496359/how-to-parse-date-string-to-date

Answer (score 2):

Change it to

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'.0'");
```

Your date is not in the format `MM/dd/yyyy`, so why did you write that? (I have no idea what the `.0` is at the end, so I just hardcoded that)

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = df.parse("2013-03-07 23:59:00.0");
```