# Convert date string from ISO 8601 format to another

Tags: java, simpledateformat

i have this piece of code , where i am trying to convert a date string from one format to another, and finally i want the date object again.

```
            String dateString = "2014-10-04";
    SimpleDateFormat oldFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date parsedDate = oldFormatter.parse(dateString);
    SimpleDateFormat newFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    String convertDateStr = newFormatter.format(parsedDate);
    Date convertedDate = newFormatter.parse(convertDateStr);
```

when i was testing above code with dateString value as "2014-10-04", the above code executes properly but the convertedDate format changed to "Sat Oct 04 00:00:00 IST 2014" instead of "dd-MMM-yyyy" format.

i have functionality like i have two dates with different format, and need to get difference in days remaining while comparing, so i need to convert one date format to other date before getting the difference in number of days.

EDIT - is there an alternate option to convert datestring to a specified format and get back date object with converted format

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse date string to Date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496359/how-to-parse-date-string-to-date)

Comment: you should first read my question clearly, it is not about parsing the date, it is about how to retain the date format after parsing

Comment: Actually you ask multiple questions: how to parse a string into a date-time, how to format a date-time as a string, why does a j.u.Date print in an alternate format, how to calculate number of days between date-time values. All of these are duplicates, having been asked and answered many times on StackOverflow. Despite this, I did post an answer to serve as a map to several different things to examine when a programmer is new to working with date-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse(            // Represent a date-only value with a date-only class.
    "2014-10-04"            // Inputs in standard ISO 8601 format are parsed by default. No need to specify a formatting pattern.
)                           // Returns a `LocalDate` object. Do not conflate a date-time object with a String that represents its value. A `LocalDate` has no “format”.
.format(                    // Generate a String representing the `LocalDate` object’s value. 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uuuu" , Locale.US )  // Define your custom formatting pattern. Specify `Locale` for human language and cultural norms used in localization.
)                           // Return a String.
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses *java.time* classes that supplanted the troublesome old legacy date-time classes such as `Date`/`Calendar`/`SimpleDateFormat`.

Use a date-only class for date-only values, rather than a date+time class. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

Your input string happens to comply with standard ISO 8601 format. The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
String input  = "2014-10-04" ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input ) ;  // No need to specify a formatting pattern for ISO 8601 inputs.
```

To generate a string representing the `LocalDate` object’s value in a particular format, define the formatting pattern. Specify a `Locale` object to determine the human language and cultural norms used in localizing.

```
Locale locale = Locale.US ; 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uuuu" , locale ) ;
String output = ld.format( f ) ;
```

> 04-Oct-2014

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

A `Date` object doesn't have format built into it, that is what the `SimpleDateFormat` does.
When you convert `convertDateStr` back into a `Date` object, you've lost the formatting.

Run these after your block of code and you'll see what I mean.

```
    System.out.println(convertedDate);
    System.out.println(newFormatter.format(convertedDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Date` object doesn't store a format for the date. That output you are seeing is simply the result of its `toString` method. If you want a date in a specific format, you must always use a formatter to get the string version of the date in the format you want.

Answer (score 0):

## Joda-Time

**UPDATE:** The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. This Answer left intact for history.

As explained in the [correct answer by forgivenson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22971201/642706) and in *many* other questions and answers found by searching StackOverflow for "java date format" or "java date parse" or such:

- A java.util.Date object has no format. A j.u.Date is not text. A j.u.Date does not contain a String. A j.u.Date object contains a number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (ignoring Leap Seconds).
- You can *generate* a String representation of the date-time value of a java.util.Date by either calling its `toString` implementation or by using a formatter.
- The `toString` method of java.util.Date is confusing in that it applies the JVM's default time zone. The result implies a j.u.Date has a time zone when in fact it does not.
- The java.util.Date and .Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. Use a decent date-time library such as [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the new java.time package bundled in Java 8.
- Your code ignores the crucial issue of time zones. A java.util.Date has a date and a time, and so you need to pay attention to time zones.
- Joda-Time and java.time both use formatting defined by the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard as their default. You may define your own formats as well, or use localized formats.

So your phrase "get back date object with converted format" is a contradiction. A date-time object (whether java.util.Date or Joda-Time or java.time) **has no format**. You are confusing the string representation generated *from* a date-time object with the date-time object itself.

Example code using Joda-Time 2.3…

```
String input = "2014-10-04";

DateTimeZone timeZoneIndia = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" );
DateTime dateTimeIndia = new DateTime( input, timeZoneIndia ); // Defaults to beginning of the day.
DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTimeIndia.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
DateTime octoberSecond = new DateTime( 2014, 10, 2, 1, 2, 3, timeZoneIndia ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();

DateTimeFormatter formatter_Iso = ISODateTimeFormat.date();
String dateTimeIndiaAsStringIso = formatter_Iso.print( dateTimeIndia );

DateTimeFormatter formatter_Dmy = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd-MM-yyyy" );
String dateTimeIndiaAsStringDmy = formatter_Dmy.print( dateTimeIndia );
DateTime dateTimeAgain = formatter_Dmy.withZone( timeZoneIndia ).parseDateTime( dateTimeIndiaAsStringDmy ); // Defaults to beginning of the day.

DateTimeFormatter formatter_Québécois = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "FF" ).withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
String dateTimeIndiaAsStringQuébécois = formatter_Québécois.print( dateTimeIndia );

int daysBetween = Days.daysBetween( octoberSecond, dateTimeIndia ).getDays();
Interval interval = new Interval( octoberSecond, dateTimeIndia );
Period period = interval.toPeriod();

java.util.Date date = dateTimeIndia.toDate();

input: 2014-10-04
dateTimeIndia: 2014-10-04T00:00:00.000+05:30
dateTimeUtc: 2014-10-03T18:30:00.000Z
octoberSecond: 2014-10-02T00:00:00.000+05:30
dateTimeIndiaAsStringIso: 2014-10-04
dateTimeIndiaAsStringDmy: 04-10-2014
dateTimeAgain: 2014-10-04T00:00:00.000+05:30
dateTimeIndiaAsStringQuébécois: samedi 4 octobre 2014 0 h 00 IST
daysBetween: 2
interval: 2014-10-02T00:00:00.000+05:30/2014-10-04T00:00:00.000+05:30
period: P2D
date: Fri Oct 03 11:30:00 PDT 2014
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "dateTimeIndia: " + dateTimeIndia );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
System.out.println( "octoberSecond: " + octoberSecond );
System.out.println( "dateTimeIndiaAsStringIso: " + dateTimeIndiaAsStringIso );
System.out.println( "dateTimeIndiaAsStringDmy: " + dateTimeIndiaAsStringDmy );
System.out.println( "dateTimeAgain: " + dateTimeAgain );
System.out.println( "dateTimeIndiaAsStringQuébécois: " + dateTimeIndiaAsStringQuébécois );
System.out.println( "daysBetween: " + daysBetween );
System.out.println( "interval: " + interval );
System.out.println( "period: " + period );
System.out.println( "date: " + date );  // Applies JVM's default time zone. North America west coast time zone in my case.
```

When run…

```
input: 2014-10-04
dateTimeIndia: 2014-10-04T00:00:00.000+05:30
dateTimeUtc: 2014-10-03T18:30:00.000Z
octoberSecond: 2014-10-02T00:00:00.000+05:30
dateTimeIndiaAsStringIso: 2014-10-04
dateTimeIndiaAsStringDmy: 04-10-2014
dateTimeAgain: 2014-10-04T00:00:00.000+05:30
dateTimeIndiaAsStringQuébécois: samedi 4 octobre 2014 0 h 00 IST
daysBetween: 2
interval: 2014-10-02T00:00:00.000+05:30/2014-10-04T00:00:00.000+05:30
period: P2D
date: Fri Oct 03 11:30:00 PDT 2014
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use this

    public static Date getDateFromString(String format, String dateStr) {

        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = (Date) formatter.parse(dateStr);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return date;
    }

    public static String getDate(Date date, String dateFormat) {
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
        return formatter.format(date);
    }
```