# How to parse a Date like this 20-Feb-2006?

Tags: java, date

i have problem of parsing a String into Date when the month contains 3 letters instead of two

Comment: What is wrong with the doc ? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-Mmm-yyy");sdf.parse("20-Feb-2006");

Comment: @bubuzzz: reading manuals is an art no longer known to many people since the advent of search engines and forums.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse date string to Date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496359/how-to-parse-date-string-to-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = df.parse("20-Feb-2006");
```

Answer (score 4):

use DateFormat in this way:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
System.out.println( df.parse("20-Feb-2006"));
```

Comment: You need to supply a locale, otherwise this might fail if the current locale does not use `Feb` for Februar (e.g. in France)

Comment: it does not work.....maybe because it is Feb and not FEB or maybe i am doing it while parsing xml

Comment: @user3505689 in my test it works fine. What is the exception you get? Or do you get a wrong date?

Answer (score 1):

USe

```
    String strDate = "20-Feb-2006";
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    Date dateStr = formatter.parse(strDate);
```