# converting string to date and converting date back to string

Tags: java

Hi for some of the requirement i need to convert the string representation of date(with no format) to date object and convert back to string(with a specific format)

This is what i tried so far, the output is not coming as expected and it's printing something like 08140009 - Any idea what is this

And please provide any suggestions.

MY code is :

```
public String getDateBackToCST(String  createDate){

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy");
    TimeZone obj = TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST");
    dateFormatter.setTimeZone(obj);
    Date createdDate = null;

    try {
        createdDate = dateFormatter.parse(createDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dateFormatter.format(createdDate);
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `createDate`?

Comment: 2014-09-14 it is having different format or it could be date string

Comment: Sat Sep 20 23:39:04 IST 2014

Comment: How can it have different format? You've explicitly put `MMddyyyy` as your parse format. Everything else will fail.

Comment: If you have more than one date format for your input string, you need to specify all those formats explicitly in your parser. I suppose you do know that in which format, you're getting the date string.

Comment: I don't understand what you expect. You've set a format. The `createDate` has to be in that format.

Comment: I have a date which i converted into CST timezone with yyyy-MM-D

Comment: yyyy-MM-DD format which is createDate and i want to change the format of it without changing the timezone info

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse date string to Date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496359/how-to-parse-date-string-to-date)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specific proper flags for SimpleDateFormat. You have 2 options to specify timezone `z` and `Z` and to specify day name use `E` like this

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class Main {



    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        String date = "Sat Sep 20 23:39:04 IST 2014 ";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy");
        System.out.println(sdf.parse(date));

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it is correct, but whenever we call parse method we will loose the timezone information which Date object will not contain. I want  the returned string to be in CST timezone

Comment: @manjunathacitragar Date object is never associated with any timezone

Comment: Yes i agree.. The String createDate  which is passed to the function is in CST timezone and when i parse it and format it back i want it to be in CST timezone only.