# Java String to Date object of the format “yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS”

Tags: java

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        java.util.Date temp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")
                .parse("2015-03-24 20:12:20.135000");
        System.out.println(temp);
```

For the same code when I use different seconds I am getting output as Tue Mar 24 20:14:35 CET 2015. I am getting everything correct except minutes and seconds. My tasks is to print the data in column which is 2015-03-24 01:55:23.999000 to round off the seconds and show it as 2015-03-24 01:55:24. Can you please tell me how it is possible or how to truncate

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse date string to Date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496359/how-to-parse-date-string-to-date)

Answer (score 7):

The [`S` format character for `SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) means milliseconds, not microseconds.

It's interpreting `135000` as 135,000 milliseconds, or 135 seconds.  Then it adds 2 minutes and 15 seconds, yielding 20:14:35 instead of 20:12:20.135.

You'll need to truncate the string to read `"2015-03-24 20:12:20.135"` so `135` milliseconds is interpreted correctly.

Comment: My tasks is to print the data in column which is  2015-03-24 01:55:23.999000 to round off the seconds and show it as 2015-03-24 01:55:24. Can you please tell me how it is possible or how to truncate?