# How to convert a Gregorian calendar date format to Julian date format?

Tags: java, sql, date

I want to convert dd-MON-yyyy to Julian date as part of SQL query against **JDE**. It would be of great help if anyone could guide on how to achieve this.

new JulianDate().ConvertToJulian(date1) worked when date1 was in **mm/dd/yyyy** format. But when date1 is in **dd-MON-yyyy** format i get the error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "16-Mar-2017"
```

In JDE, the date is stored in Julian Format.

Please note here mm/dd/yyyy and dd-MON-yyyy are all in string format.

Hence `DateFormat`, `SimpleDateFormat`, etc cannot be applied.

Also in SQL i believe it is dd-MON-yyyy format and not dd-MMM-yyyy format.

Comment: Not "MON"; it's "MMM".  Please read the docs.

Comment: Where's the SQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse date string to Date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496359/how-to-parse-date-string-to-date)

Comment: Why the SQL tag?

Comment: The ANSI SQL format is `DATE'YYYY-MM-DD'`, e.g. `DATE'2017-03-16'`.

Comment: If you want to do it in SQL, why are you trying to do it in Java? --- Hint for others: The `MON` format is used by Oracle DB, see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#r27c1-t64).

Comment: @jarlh i want to include the date as part of SQL query in the where clause

Comment: When it comes to date/time many dbms products are far from ANSI SQL compliant. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @Andreas it is part of java code

Comment: Why can't you use `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat`? What is preventing you from using it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: @user7324003 By “JDE” do you mean [JD Edwards EnterpriseOne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JD_Edwards)? Please expand such acronyms or use a Tag on your Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `dd-MMM-yyyy` format for this.

Take a look at the code below. This converts given date format to Julian format.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateFormatConverter {

    private String inputDateFormat;
    private String outputDateFormat;

    private DateFormatConverter (String inputDateFormat, String outputDateFormat) {
        this.inputDateFormat = inputDateFormat;
        this.outputDateFormat = outputDateFormat;
    }

    private String convert(String inputDate) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat idf = new SimpleDateFormat(inputDateFormat);
        SimpleDateFormat odf = new SimpleDateFormat(outputDateFormat);
        Date date = idf.parse(inputDate);
        String outputDate = odf.format(date);
        return outputDate;
    }

    public static String toJulian(String inputFormat, String inputDate) throws ParseException {
        String suffixFormat = "yyDDD";
        String prefixFormat = "yyyy";
        String suffix = new DateFormatConverter(inputFormat, suffixFormat).convert(inputDate);
        int centuryPrefix = Integer.parseInt(new DateFormatConverter(inputFormat, prefixFormat).convert(inputDate).substring(0, 2))-19;
        return centuryPrefix+suffix;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String jd = DateFormatConverter.toJulian("dd-MMM-yyyy", "01-Jan-2017");
        System.out.println(jd);
    }

}
```

> *Extra*:

Refer to this info about Julian dates:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26228_01/doc.93/e21961/julian_date_conv.htm#WEAWX259

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for the detailed code. I want to convert the date to Julian format.

Comment: Thank you so much. I converted to Julian format after carrying out the conversion as you said.

Comment: i am new to date formatting and all the queries above were confusing me. Thank you for the help. @anacron

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Comment: @BasilBourque. That's true. We can incorporate those changes too.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( 
    "16-Mar-2017" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uuuu" , Locale.US )
)
```

## java.time

The modern approach is with java.time classes. Avoid the notoriously troublesome old date-time classes, now legacy.

### Parse date string

Parse the date string by defining a formatting pattern to match. Specify a `Locale` for human language to use in translating the name of the month.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uuuu" , Locale.US );
String input = "16-Mar-2017" ;
```

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( input , f );
```

### JD Edwards EnterpriseOne date format

If by `JDE` you meant “JD Edwards EnterpriseOne”, those systems use an unusual format for representing a date-only value as a string, `CYYDDD` where:

- `C` = Century, 0 for 1900s, 1 for 2000s. Add to `19` to get century number, multiply by `100` to get year number.
- `YY` = Year of the century.
- `DDD` = Day of year, running 1 to 365 (or 366 in Leap Year).

Let's build up a String in that format.

```
// Build output in CYYDDD format used by JD Edwards EnterpriseOne.
int c = ( ( localDate.getYear ( ) / 100 ) - 19 );
String yy = ( String.valueOf ( localDate.getYear ( ) ) ).substring ( 2 ); // Substring of positions 3-4, index numbering is 2.
String ddd = String.format ( "%03d", localDate.getDayOfYear ( ) );
String output = c + yy + ddd ;
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ("input: " + input );
System.out.println ( "output: " + output );
```

When run.

> input: 16-Mar-2017
>
> output: 117075

Now go the other direction, parsing a JDE date string to get a `LocalDate`. We extract the century code of `1`, add it to `19`, and multiply by a hundred, and lastly add the two digits for year-of-century. From that integer year number we create a [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html) object. By feeding that `Year` object the parsed integer number for day-of-year, we get a `LocalDate` object.

```
// Going the other direction, parsing CYYDDD to get a `LocalDate`.
String cyyddd = "117075";
String c_ = cyyddd.substring ( 0, 0 + 1 ); // Index-counting, zero-based.
String yy_ = cyyddd.substring ( 1, 1 + 2 );
String ddd_ = cyyddd.substring ( 3 );
Year year = Year.of ( ( ( Integer.valueOf ( c_ ) + 19 ) * 100 ) + Integer.valueOf ( yy_ ) );
LocalDate ld = year.atDay( Integer.valueOf ( ddd_ ));
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ("cyyddd: " + cyyddd );
System.out.println ("ld: " + ld );
```

> cyyddd: 117075
>
> ld: 2017-03-16

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for such detailed explanation. :) a 100 up votes for this.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

```
String date1="dd-MMM-yyyy";
String date2="MM/dd/yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat idf = new SimpleDateFormat(date1);
SimpleDateFormat odf = new SimpleDateFormat(date2);
Date dateFrom = idf.parse(fromDate);
Date dateTo = idf.parse(toDate);
```

And then to convert to Julian Date i used:

```
new JulianDate().ConvertToJulian(odf.format(dateFrom));
new JulianDate().ConvertToJulian(odf.format(dateTo));
```

Hoping somebody would find it useful in future.