# How to convert input date into real date in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, wordpress

I have a date input field when I enter the date and do the alert in this given me 123476890017 something like this. anybody can help me on this?

If I enter the date like this 12/07/2017 and in the alert, the result should come 2017/07/12.

HTML code:

```
<input type="date" placeholder="search" ng-model="date">
```

script

```
 function formatDate(date) {
         alert(date);
 }
```

Comment: try `var x =  123476890017;`

`var y = new Date(x)`

Comment: why you are taking complicate? . just use date filter. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's also very easy using a library like [**Moment.js**](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/):

```
moment("12/07/2017", "DD/MM/YYYY").format("YYYY/MM/DD");
=> "2017/07/12"
```

Comment: Why using a whole library just for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.date = 1506413232120;
   $scope.new_date = new Date($scope.date);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 {{new_date | date : 'yyyy/MM/dd' }}
</div>
```

Comment: thank you Mr. Raghav, but i want to use ParseDate function. can you help me??? i dont know how to parse a input date string to real date.

Comment: This may help you take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496359/how-to-parse-date-string-to-date

Comment: @KKSK "*i want to use ParseDate function*"... well then you should specify that in your question! You're not going to get answers to do what you want, if you don't tell us what that is.

Answer (score 0):

Use date filter.   [Click here for more details about date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

```
$filter('date')(date, format, timezone)  

$scope.newDate =   $filter('date')($scope.date, "dd-MM-yyyy");
```

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
  //$filter('date')(date, format, timezone) 
$scope.newDate =   $filter('date')($scope.date, "dd-MM-yyyy");

$scope.take = function(date){
$scope.newDate =   $filter('date')(date, "yyyy-MM-dd");
console.log($scope.newDate);
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
  <input type="date" ng-model="date" ng-change="take(date)">
</div>
```