# Parsing from String to Date throws Unparsable Date Error

Tags: java, date

I have an variable called `data`, and it has today's date as in this format: `Thu May 24 13:14:41 BRT 2018`. Then I format it to MySQL's Date type format, which is `yyyy-MM-dd`. This code does it:

```
String dataFormatada = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(data);
```

What I want to do is to bring it back to Date type. I've tried somethings but they didn't work. The main solution is to do as discribed in this other [Stack Overflow's questioin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496359/how-to-parse-date-string-to-date), and with a little mod I got to what's suposely what I want:

```
String target = "Thu Sep 28 20:29:30 JST 2000";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date result =  df.parse(target);  
System.out.println(result);
```

But it doesn't work as I get this error when trying to parse:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Sep 28 20:29:30 JST 2000"
```

So I cannot just reformat the `data` variable, and I cannot bring `dataFormatada` back to Date format. How do I bring `dataFormatada` to Date type formatted as yyyy-MM-dd?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your target String format is in `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy` format. So you need to use `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy` as pattern instead of `yyyy-MM-dd`.

```
    String target = "Thu Sep 28 20:29:30 JST 2000";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date result =  df.parse(target);  
    System.out.println(result);
```

And if you want convert Date object i.e result to `yyyy-MM-dd` then please use the below code.

```
    DateFormat dfDateToStr = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String formattedDate  = dfDateToStr.format(result);
    System.out.println("Formatted Date String : "+formattedDate);
```

Comment: This gives me a date in the "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy" format. I need the final Date type to be "yyyy-MM-dd"

Comment: @William You are getting the result as a `Date object` and `Date` really don't have any format. When you print it call Date#toString

Answer (score 2):

You need two formator, one to parse the orginal string to `Date` object, one to format it to desired string:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String target = "Thu Sep 28 20:29:30 JST 2000";
    DateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date result = parser.parse(target);
    System.out.println(result);

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String dataFormatada = format.format(result);
}
```

Comment: This method gives me, at the end of it, a String with the correct format, but I need a Date, not string, Mr. @Neng Liu

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

For a SQL-standard `DATE` column, use the `java.time.LocalDate` class with JDBC 4.2 or later.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject(
    … ,
    ZonedDateTime.parse(  // Represent a moment in a particular time zone.
        "Thu May 24 13:14:41 BRT 2018".replace( "BRT" , "Europe/London" ) ,
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z uuuu" , Locale.UK )
    )
    .toLocalDate()        // Extract a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone.
)
```

## ISO 8601

> I have an variable called data, and it has today's date as in this format: Thu May 24 13:14:41 BRT 201

This is a *terrible* format. When exchanging date-time values as text, use only the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. Conveniently, the *java.time* classes use these formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

## `BST` = ?? (Brazil Standard Time, British Standard Time, … )

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `BST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

The `ZonedDateTime` class will try to guess the intended time zone. But you should *not* be relying on guesses in your code.

```
String input = "Thu May 24 13:14:41 BRT 2018";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z uuuu" , Locale.UK );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

> 2018-05-24T13:14:41-03:00[America/Sao_Paulo]

Looks like *java.time* guessed you meant `Brazil Standard Time` by `BST`. If you meant some other zone such as British time, replace that `BST` string by a proper time zone name.

Specify [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

```
String input = "Thu May 24 13:14:41 BRT 2018".replace( "BRT" , "Europe/London" );
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z uuuu" , Locale.UK );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

> 2018-05-24T13:14:41+01:00[Europe/London]

## `LocalDate`

You apparently care about only the date. So extract a date-only object, a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

## Smart objects, not dumb strings

Do not exchange date-time values with your database as text. Instead use JDBC and objects. As of JDBC 4.2 and later, you can directly exchange *java.time* objects with your database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Rather British Summer Time. Just to underline the confusion.