# Comparing dates with months as strings

Tags: java, date, date-comparison

I am trying to compare these two dates :

```
17 Oct. 2019 (08:23)
19 déc. 2019 (21:15)
```

The months are in French and the main problem is the months. Do I need to put an if statement for every type of month so I can switch it with the appropriate month? For example:

```
if (MonthValue.equals("oct."){
    DateValue.replace("oct.","10");
}
```

Or is there an easier solution, because I need to check in a table if the first value is bigger than the second one.

Edit :
My new Code :

```
String target1 = "17 oct. 2019 (08:23)";
        String target2 = "19 déc. 2019 (21:15)";
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM. YYYY (kk:mm)", Locale.FRENCH);
        Date result =  df.parse(target1);  
        Date result2 =  df.parse(target2); 
        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println(result2);
        if(result.compareTo(result2) < 0) {
            System.out.println("true");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("false");
        }
```

Doesn't work gives this error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "17 oct. 2019 (08:23)"
```

Comment: Do you need to compare with String? why don't you parse to date and then compare it.

Comment: @Jelle The goal is clearly to compare 2 dates, what the reasoning behind that isn't really required by us.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496359/how-to-parse-date-string-to-date this will probably point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez the goal is to compare two things either they both become date or they both become string but i want use string since with string i cant check if the first value is bigger than the second one

Comment: Look at Date.parseDate().  Also understand how locales work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse date string to Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496359/how-to-parse-date-string-to-date)

Comment: @Popeye will it work for french too so my patern should be something like this String Pattern = " dd MMM. YYYY (kk:mm)"

Comment: Yes, you should be able to set Locale on it.

Comment: @Popeye The solution you linked uses legacy classses though. It's highly recommended to use the Date & Time API introduced in Java SE 8.

Comment: @Popeye it's not working either way and i dont have the smallest idea about the reason

Comment: Has that string really got an upper case `O`in `Oct.`? That’s not usual where I read French.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: yeah that's what the answer uses @OleV.V.

Comment: I believe the comment by Ole V.V. refers to your use of uppercase “O” in your example data, `17 Oct. 2019 (08:23)`. In French cultures that I’ve seen, that should be `oct` rather than `Oct`.

Comment: I suggest you educate the publisher of your data about the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. They should not be using localized text for exchanging date-time values.

Comment: @BasilBourque i wish i could but the one who did it quit and the new one cant change it since he doesnt know what it might change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### java.time and optional parts in the format pattern string

Like the others I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. I understand that if your month names are five letters or shorter (for example *avril*), they are written out in full, whereas if they are seven letters or longer (for example *juillet*), they are abbreviated. The following formatter can parse in both situations:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER
        = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .parseCaseInsensitive()
                .appendPattern("dd [MMMM][MMM] uuuu (HH:mm)")
                .toFormatter(Locale.FRENCH);
```

Square brackets `[]` in the format pattern string surround optional parts. `MMMM` is for full month name. `MMM` is for the abbreviation. So the point in `[MMMM][MMM]` is that it will successfully parse either full month name or abbreviations and just skip the one that doesn’t work. Since you gave an example of `Oct.` being written with an upper case `O`, I have also specified that the parsing should not be sensitive to case. If this is not necessary, you may use this simpler formatter:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd [MMMM][MMM] uuuu (HH:mm)", Locale.FRENCH);
```

In order to check that all months work, I have set up these test data:

```
    String[] dateStrings = {
            "17 Oct. 2019 (08:23)",
            "19 déc. 2019 (21:15)",
            "01 avril 2021 (09:40)",
            "08 janv. 2020 (01:18)",
            "28 févr. 2021 (21:41)",
            "03 mars 2020 (22:54)",
            "06 mai 2020 (03:14)",
            "21 juin 2020 (07:15)",
            "18 juil. 2020 (23:06)",
            "06 août 2020 (22:28)",
            "29 sept. 2020 (06:04)",
            "18 nov. 2019 (01:35)"
    };
```

To parse and compare two of them use `LocalDateTime.parse()` and `.isBefore()`:

```
    LocalDateTime dateTime1 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateStrings[1], DATE_FORMATTER);
    LocalDateTime dateTime2 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateStrings[2], DATE_FORMATTER);
    if (dateTime1.isBefore(dateTime2)) {
        System.out.format(Locale.FRENCH, "%s is before %s%n", dateTime1, dateTime2);
    }
```

Output:

> 2019-12-19T21:15 is before 2021-04-01T09:40

For comparison you may also exploit the fact that `LocalDateTime` implements `Comparable`. This is practical when sorting the dates and times, for example. As a brief example let’s sort all the `LocalDateTime` objects that come out of parsing the above strings:

```
    Arrays.stream(dateStrings)
            .map(ds -> LocalDateTime.parse(ds, DATE_FORMATTER))
            .sorted()
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

> ```
> 2019-10-17T08:23
> 2019-11-18T01:35
> 2019-12-19T21:15
> 2020-01-08T01:18
> 2020-03-03T22:54
> 2020-05-06T03:14
> 2020-06-21T07:15
> 2020-07-18T23:06
> 2020-08-06T22:28
> 2020-09-29T06:04
> 2021-02-28T21:41
> 2021-04-01T09:40
> ```

**Link:** [Trail: Date Time (The Java™ Tutorials)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 2):

Using DateTimeFormatter with pattern `dd MMM yyyy (HH:mm)` to parse the date string like this

```
String target1 = "17 oct. 2019 (08:23)";
String target2 = "19 déc. 2019 (21:15)";

Locale locale = Locale.FRANCE;
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("dd MMM yyyy (HH:mm)")
        .toFormatter(locale);
LocalDateTime dateTime1 = LocalDateTime.parse(target1, dateTimeFormatter);
LocalDateTime dateTime2 = LocalDateTime.parse(target2, dateTimeFormatter);

System.out.println(dateTime1);
System.out.println(dateTime2);
if (dateTime1.compareTo(dateTime2) < 0) {
    System.out.println("true");
} else {
    System.out.println("false");
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked it seems that the . next to the MMM was the probleme if i am not wrong ?

Comment: @Yan Yes, the point is characters of the month itself

Comment: Or without the builder: `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy (HH:mm)", Locale.FRENCH)`.

Comment: The main problem was the `.` which already is covered by `MMM` and especially `YYYY` which is the weekyear, `yyyy` is the normal year. On year change the week number can correspond to a (week-)year different of the actual year.

Comment: @Yan also the "oct." instead of "Oct."

Comment: Fine suggestion. I would use `dateTime1.isBefore(dateTime2)` instead of `compareTo()`.

Comment: @zephyr another question please this format works for most of them by some months that doesnt go past 6 letters dont get parsed and crash the app is there a solution for this Ex: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '01 avril 2021 (09:40)' could not be parsed at index 3

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation:

- parse the dates e.g. with a [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to e.g. a [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)
- compare the parsed dates (most date and time objects implement https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html)

Comment: doesnt work gives this error java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "17 oct. 2019 (08:23)"

Comment: @Yan parsing should work, the right Locale and format given (so it knows the month names, abbreviated). This is actually the best solution from both.

Comment: The method format(String, Object...) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (DateTimeFormatter) i got this error after putting my pattern and my value

Comment: @Yan please update your question with what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

What I've got from your question is that you want to convert Month's names to their respective numbers. If this is the case, then you should try **switch** 
Example:

```
switch (MonthValue){
    case jan:
      MonthValue = 1; // Set Month variable to it Numbered Position (type casting might be required)
      break;
    case feb:
      MonthValue = 2;
      break;
    default:
      System.out.println("Somthing...");
}
```

Comment: i don't want to do this since if it will compare 1000 values it wan't be efficient

Answer (score -1):

Try encoding to UTF8, which will avoid DateTimeParseException
`Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '19 d??c. 2019 (21:15)' could not be parsed at index 3`

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String date1 = "17 oct. 2019 (08:23)";
        String date2 = "19 déc. 2019 (21:15)";
        
        DateTimeFormatter longDateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy (HH:mm)").withLocale(Locale.FRENCH);
        LocalDateTime lclDate1 = LocalDateTime.parse(encodeUTF8(date1), longDateTimeFormatter);
        LocalDateTime lclDate2 = LocalDateTime.parse(encodeUTF8(date2), longDateTimeFormatter);
        if (lclDate1.compareTo(lclDate2) < 0) {
            System.out.println("true");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("false");
        }
    }
    
    public static String encodeUTF8(String dateStr) {
        byte[] bytes = dateStr.getBytes();
        String utf8EncodStr = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        return utf8EncodStr;
    }
```

Comment: This is not correct. You're encoding the String to the platform default ecodiing, then decoding the bytes to  back to a String using UTF_8. Odds are your platform default is UTF_8 so this is a non-op.

Comment: And UTF-8 will be the [default across platforms](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/400) in Java 18 and later.